# WebSocketListener в OkHttp

Tags: android, websocket, okhttp

Всем привет! Реализую подключение к серверу по вебсокету. В процессе стоклнулся с вопросом: какой метод WebSocketListener срабатывает, если во время подключения на телефоне отключили мобильный интернет? И, какой метод срабатывает, если связь пропала со стороны сервера. т.е., например, сервер просто упал.
Вот все методы WebSocketListener:

```
onClosed(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason)
onClosing(WebSocket webSocket, int code, String reason)
onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response)
onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, okio.ByteString bytes)
onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text)
onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response)
```

Не смог найти информации или статей по своему вопросу, поэтому решил задать его здесь.

Answer (score 1):

При ошибке будет вызван метод
`onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response)`